# How can I find the owner of a LinkedIn App?

Tags: linkedin-api

I recently joined a new company that has an existing LinkedIn app for API access. We use this to link our user accounts with a LinkedIn account. It is currently functioning as intended, but no one in the company knows who created the app, or what account was used to create it.

I have tried logging in to the developer portal with all our company accounts, none have the app associated. I have the app_id, the client_id and client_secret, but I can't find any documentation on how to get info about the app. LinkedIn support provided a canned response to try Stack Overflow or their developer documentation.